# get records from multible table with specific search

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

I am working on a library automation system.

**TABLES**

```
book(id,name,author,code)

student(id, name,surname,number)

lend_book(id, book_id[fk from book],student_id,lend_date,receive_case)
```

{  student_id and book_id foreging key, receive_case is tinyint(1) }

So I need a sql query how it search with book name,author or code AND/OR(if user entry it) student name,surname or number AND/OR book is received, not received or both of cases.

```
query = "SELECT s.name, s.surname,s.number,b.name, b.code, b.author,lb.lend_date,l.delivery_date from student"+
                    "JOIN  book b ON (b.name like '%{1}%' OR b.code like '%{1}%' OR b.code like '%{1}%')" +
                    "JOIN lend_book lb ON (lb.recieve_case={2})"+
                    "WHERE (s.name like '%{0}%' OR s.surname like '%{0}%' OR s.number like '%{0}%') ;";
```

Thanks

Comment: And what's the question? Is there anything wrong with the sql code you wrote?

Comment: It gave me syntx error 
"'b ON (b.name like '%%' OR b.code like '%%' OR b.code like '%%')JOIN lend_book lb' "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone i solve it.

```
  "SELECT DISTINCT s.name, s.surname,s.number,b.name, b.code, b.author,lb.lend_date,lb.delivery_date from student s " +
  " JOIN lend_book lb ON (lb.recieve_case={2} OR lb.recieve_case={2})" +
  " JOIN  book b ON (b.name like '%{1}%' OR b.code like '%{1}%' OR b.code like '%{1}%') " +
  " JOIN student ON (s.name like '%{0}%' OR s.surname like '%{0}%' OR s.number like '%{0}%')"+
  " WHERE s.id=lb.student_id AND b.id=lb.book_id;";
```

Answer (score 1):

SELECT b.Id, b.Name, b.Code, s.Id, s.Name, s.Surname, s.Number, l.lend_date, l.receive_case

FROM book b
    LEFT OUTER JOIN lend_book l ON b.id = l.book_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN student s ON s.id = l.student_id

WHERE 
   (b.Name like '%{0}%' OR b.author like '%{1}%' OR b.code like '%{2}%')
   AND/OR
   (s.Name like '%{3}%' OR s.surname like '%{4}%' OR s.number like '%{5}%')
   AND/OR
   (l.receive_case = {6} OR {6} IS NULL)

if value of {6} is 1, it will return where receive case =1.
if value of {6} is 0, it will return where receive case =0.
To get all records in both the cases, value of {6} should be null. Or if null is not suitable in your case then you can take any number other than 0/1 and change the last condition to {6} =

Comment: Thanks sir but it gave me syntx error like 'b LEFT OUTER JOIN lend_book l ON b.id = l.book_id LEFT OUTER JOIN student s ON s'